# php outcome of sum multiply with html element

Tags: php, html

Excuse me if the title isn't completely clear.

but i've got a value that is the outcome of a sum. Called `$addCols` and a variable that is just html. What i want is to repeat the html with the addCols variable.

```
$addCols = 4 //for example
$html .= '<div>test</div>';
```

And i wish to get the following result:

```
// Result
test
test
test
test
```

What i've tried:

```
$result = $addCols * $html;
echo $result;
```

Comment: if variable is paul and you want to multiply it with 2 then answer should
paul 
paul

right?

Comment: yes that is what i meant. The answer of NoLiver92 below is just what i was looking for. But thanks for the quick respons!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a built-in function for this:

```
echo str_repeat("<div>test</div>", $addCols);
```

[Documentation](http://php.net/str-repeat)

Built-in functions will always be better/faster than manually-coded solutions.

Comment: Thanks "str_repeat" is better. it's been a while since i've had done something with php code. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

create a for loop, this will post the html code as many times as your variable states giving the requested output.

```
for($x = 0; $x < $addCols; $x++)
{
  echo '<div>text</div>';
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much, it's exactly what i mean. I wil accept your answer in 10min.

Comment: Glad I could help, but your question isnt very clear. Suggest you sar repeated 4 times instead of multiplied as multiplied implies its all numbers

Comment: Not quite right - should be `$x < $addCols`, otherwise you get one more than intended.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Good point, slight oversight on my part. Updated code

Comment: Please don't upvote this anymore, ```str_repeat``` is **much** better.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `str_repeat()` function in php or run a loop. Use the code below
With str_repeat

```
$addCols = 4 ;//for example
$html = '<div>test</div>';
echo str_repeat($html, $addCols);
```

With loop

```
 $addCols = 4; //for example
    $html = '<div>test</div>';
    for($x = 0; $x < $addCols; $x++)
    {
      echo $html;
    }
```

With while loop

```
$html = '<div>test</div>';
 $addCols = 4 ;//for example
$x=0;
   while($x < $addCols)
    {
      echo $html;
    $x++;
    }
```

Hope this helps you

Comment: I just took the ideas that's not the harm in php

Comment: @NoLiver92 Gave one more method

Comment: @NoLiver92 Bye the way +1 for your answer